SSRS data driven subscription GetReportParametersAction Error
I have Azure VM database which I use as a source for my DB Source. My SSRS server generates Data Driven report emails out of this db and always have intermittent problems while running my process (email goes to 20+ users). Most of the time I have like Done: 8 processed of 8 total; 4 errors. .Never had 100% success.  I've tested very same process to ran against  traditional non VM SQL Server where I have 0 errors.  Also tested it on conventional SQL db, with the same results
I've checked logs, there are multiple errors, like The subscription contains parameter values that are not valid. And others like below .
SOme of the related to Oracle, Terradata which is not really related to my setup ,but I think this is common calls which are failing, so maybe this cause whole problems.
in each case different Parameters are failing, so all of them are valid. So it's false error.
Anybody can advice what  Ican do to make it right ?
 elibrary!ReportServer_0-24!15f8!07/25/2024-14:37:16:: i INFO: Call to GetItemTypeAction(/Mills0000_Alpha_Customer). User: MayData\saccount.
extensionfactory!ReportServer_0-24!15bc!07/25/2024-14:37:16:: e ERROR: Exception caught instantiating TERADATA report server extension: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Teradata.Client.Provider, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=76b417ee2e04956c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.



library!ReportServer_0-24!15f8!07/25/2024-14:37:16:: i INFO: Call to GetReportParametersAction(/Mills0000_Alpha_Customer). User: MayData\saccount.
extensionfactory!ReportServer_0-24!15bc!07/25/2024-14:37:16:: e ERROR: Exception caught instantiating ORACLE report server extension: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.




   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
extensionfactory!ReportServer_0-24!ab8!07/25/2024-14:40:43:: e ERROR: Exception caught instantiating DAX report server extension: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error.  ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.Cloud.DataExtensions' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..

extensionfactory!ReportServer_0-24!1d98!07/25/2024-14:40:43:: e ERROR: Exception caught instantiating TERADATA report server extension: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Teradata.Client.Provider, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=76b417ee2e04956c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

 at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.ExtensionClassFactory.CreateExtensionObject(Extension extConfig, Boolean typeOnly).
extensionfactory!ReportServer_0-24!1d98!07/25/2024-14:40:43:: e ERROR: Exception caught instantiating ORACLE report server extension: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.


   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.ExtensionClassFactory.CreateExtensionObject(Extension extConfig, Boolean typeOnly).
extensionfactory!ReportServer_0-24!1d98!07/25/2024-14:40:43:: e ERROR: Exception caught instantiating SQLPDW report server extension: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

All those Params in error are not recorded in SSRS db.
SELECT c.[Name], 
       el.UserName, 
       el.[Parameters],
       el.TimeStart
FROM ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLog el
INNER JOIN ReportServer.dbo.[Catalog] c ON el.ReportID = c.ItemID
WHERE c.[Name] LIKE  '%myRep%'
AND el.TimeStart >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()-2)
ORDER BY  el.TimeStart DESC

Collation is like below and the same between my test SQL server and Azure
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
Also noticed that lower vs Upper case makes different, which totally doesn't' make sense.

I also tested this subscription on FileShare distribution with the same inconsistent results, some  params just don't recorded into ReportServer  and there is not any output.
So it's not about Email Server errors, all my params works OK and produce output running in sql format  sp_My_Proc 'AlphaBravo'.   Params in SQL could be lower or upper case, doesn't matter.

Also dummied param in my sp, it's still same bad results.
